# Vim: Select text between brackets including new line character

Tags: vim

I have this code:

```
import {
  one,
  two,
  three,
  four,
} from "../myfile";
```

I am trying to delete everything between the curly braces. I position my cursor anywhere between (or on) the curly braces and type `di{`. I am getting this:

```
import {
} from "../myfile";
```

When I am expecting this:

```
import {} from "../myfile";
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5):

There is no dedicated way to achieve that.

Here is how I do it:

```
caB{}<Esc>
```

But you could do it like this:

```
diBkJx
```

or like this:

```
gwiBdiB
```

or possibly a dozen other ways.

You can map it to something easier for the fingers if you need to do that often.

Reference:

```
:help c
:help aB
:help d
:help iB
:help k
:help J
:help x
:help gw
```

---EDIT---

FWIW, I've been puzzled by that behaviour for years.

I think the core of the issue is that there is no text after the `{` on the same line and no text before the `}` on the same line, but *which* character seems important.

```
import {___(3 spaces)  If you append characters of _any_ kind to {,
  one,                 including whitespace, then the selection
  two,                 includes them.
} from "../myfile";

import {xxx
  one,
  two,
} from "../myfile";
```

[image: append whitespace]
[image: append non-whitespace]

```
import {xxx            If you prepend whitespace characters to },
  one,                 then they are ignored.
  two,
  } from "../myfile";
```

[image: prepend only whitespace]

```
import {xxx            If there is even _one_ non-whitespace
  one,                 character in those prepended to },
  two,                 then the selection includes them all.
 x } from "../myfile";
```

[image: prepend mixed characters]

I am really not sure about the rationale, here.

Comment: Any idea why `diB` behaves this way? The help says that the text object selects the text between the brackets, meaning that it should include the new line.

Comment: @yankolo, see my edit.